# Replace one div with another - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, replacewith

I have 4 divs and in each one there are top and down arrows.
If user click top arrow - current div change place with higher div and conversely.

How can I do this?
This code is for "bottom arrow" and doesnt work...

```
$("button.down").click(function(){

var aDiv = $(this).parent();
var dDiv = $(this).parent().next("div");

$(this).parent().next("div").replaceWith(aDiv);
$(this).parent().replaceWith(dDiv);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gjkhf81u/

Comment: You're going to have to provide alot more if you want help with this; it's really hard to derive what you're actually doing with this.

Comment: It is best to ccreate as jsfiddle that includes all code and HTML as well as the jquery version you are using.

Comment: Ok. Will edit in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27799934/227299) mentioned, you want to use [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore) and [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter).

When you insert a node in a different place in the DOM, it gets moved.

```js
$("button.down").click(function(){
  var aDiv = $(this).parents(".container");
  var nextDiv = aDiv.next(".container");
  aDiv.insertAfter(nextDiv);
});

$("button.up").click(function(){
  var aDiv = $(this).parents(".container");
  var prevDiv = aDiv.prev(".container");
  aDiv.insertBefore(prevDiv);
});
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color: green;" class="container">
<button class="up">Up</button>
<button class="down">Down</button>
</div>

<div style="background-color: red;" class="container">
<button class="up">Up</button>
<button class="down">Down</button>
</div>

<div style="background-color: yellow;" class="container">
<button class="up">Up</button>
<button class="down">Down</button>
</div>

<div style="background-color: blue;" class="container">
<button class="up">Up</button>
<button class="down">Down</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore):

```
var div = $(theCurrentDiv);
var prev = div.prev();
if (prev[0]) {
    div.insertBefore(div.prev());
}
```

That code moves the current div to in front of its sibling, if any. There's also the related [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before), which goes the other way.

`insertBefore` example:

```js
$("input[type=button]").click(function() {
  var div = $(".current");
  var prev = div.prev();
  if (prev[0]) {
    div.insertBefore(prev);
  }
});
```

```css
.current {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Up">
<div>
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div class="current">four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could swap the contents of the divs?

```
<div class="x"> Hello World </div>
<div class="y"> Bye World </div>

    $("button.down").click(function() {
        var temp = $(".x").html();
        $(".x").html() = $(".y").html();
        $(".y").html() = temp;
    });
```

Comment: That makes the browser do a lot more work and destroys any event handlers on any elements in the divs. Still, we're talking about doing it in response to a click, so performance isn't a concern, and the OP didn't mention event handlers on div contents. But I wouldn't. :-)

Comment: I agree, your way is much more efficient. I just thought OP might understand this way a little more given his wording and this requires minimal performance capacities anyway :P 

100% no for anything larger than this, agreed.